# manage multiple sites with a single login

Tags: multi-sites, aegir

My client wants urls site1.com and site2.com that share the same codebase for everything but the theme. They want different node content on each site.

They also want the ability to login to one location site1/user, and be able to update content from both sites there.

Is this possible with a multi-site install or Aegir?

If there are two different databases, it seems that you could not update content from both sites in one Drupal admin panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you might be looking for the [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) module

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database.

Comment: this seems like I can control what nodes are published on what domain, but can I also change the themes?

Comment: [Allegedly, yes](https://drupal.org/node/1091294#comment-5039150) :)

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to create on the node where the content is published. If I can assign to one url or both.

Comment: I believe that's the case, I only used it once bit im pretty sure it does that too

Comment: domain access solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do the old sharing tables thing. It's simple and assuming your hosting everything on the same server it should work fine. Also assuming it's close to drupal in the way it handles SQL.

https://drupal.org/node/22267 - describes the process fairly well